# Syntax issue with passing value by reference in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to make a bit of code that dynamically updates Windows Forms elements to integrate some back-end code I have with forms, but am running into a small speed-bump in the syntax.

Right now the code I have is this:

```
public virtual class DynamicDisplay
{
    private Control c;
    public DynamicDisplay(ref Control display)
    {
        c = display;
    }
    //interprets the attribute visually and shows it in the control
    public abstract void ShowVal(double valToDisplay);
}
public class ProgBarDynamicDisplay : DynamicDisplay
{
    private double max;
    public ProgBarDynamicDisplay(ProgressBar p, double nMax) : base(ref p)
    {
        max = nMax;
    }
}
```

But this is giving me a "mismatched methods" error. Does anyone know the syntax I should be using to pass the progress bar by reference to the superclass?

Comment: In your example, passing by ref makes no sense. Just drop the ref.

Comment: 1) `Control` is a reference type, not a value type, you're passing a reference by reference, not a value by reference. 2) When you store it in a field you're taking a copy of its value (which is a reference), and not maintaining a reference to the reference. 3) I have *no idea* what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: That `virtual class` is probably meant to be an `abstract class`.

Comment: Smells like a c++ coder migrating to c#

Comment: @AhmetKakıcı don't forget to de-reference you're referenced pointers with a reference! ...or something like that :p  But yeah, using `ref` is almost never necessary in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
public abstract class DynamicDisplay
{
   private Control c;
   public DynamicDisplay(Control display)
   {
       c = display;
   }

   //interprets the attribute visually and shows it in the control
   public abstract void ShowVal(double valToDisplay);
}

public class ProgBarDynamicDisplay : DynamicDisplay
{
   private double max;
   public ProgBarDynamicDisplay(ProgressBar p, double nMax)
            : base( p)
   {
            max = nMax;
   }

 public override void ShowVal(double valToDisplay)
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Value : " + valToDisplay);
 }   
}
```

To test:

```
namespace TestProject3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar();
            TestProject3.Class1.ProgBarDynamicDisplay pbdr = new     TestProject3.Class1.ProgBarDynamicDisplay(p, 100);
            pbdr.ShowVal(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `ref`  in the constructor for `DynamicDisplay`  since you aren't reassigning to `display` in that function.  Just drop the `ref` and you should be fine. Also get rid of `ref` where you call `base(ref p)`